# C++ Unresolved Token Issue

Tags: c++, token

I am doing a program for a class and the teacher gave us a Cpp file that we had to implement. All was written by him except Main but I am getting a weird error. Any help would be great. Here is my code.

```
// **************************************************************************
//
// Counter.cpp
//
// Defines and tests class CounterType, which is used to count things.
// CounterType contains both a default constructor and a constructor that
// sets the count to a specified value, plus methods to increment, decrement,
// return, and output the count.  The count is always nonnegative.
//
// **************************************************************************
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class CounterType
{
public:
    CounterType();
    //Initializes the count to 0.

    CounterType(int initCount);
    //Precondition: initCount holds the initial value for the count.
    //Postcondition:
    //  If initCount > 0,initializes the count to initCount.
    //  If initCount <= 0,initializes the count to 0.

    void increment();
    //Postcondition:
    //  The count is one more than it was.

    void decrement();
    //Postcondition:
    //  If the count was positive, it is now one less than it was.
    //  If the count was 0, it is still 0

    int getCount();
    void output(ostream& outStream);
    //Precondition: outStream is ready to write to
    //Postcondition: count has been written to outStream

private:
    int count;

};

 void increment();
 void decrement();
 int getCount();
 void output(ostream& outStream);

 int main()
{
    CounterType Test;

    increment();
    decrement();
    getCount();

}

CounterType::CounterType()
{
    count = 0;
}

CounterType::CounterType(int initCount)
{
    if (initCount >= 0)
        count = initCount;
    else
        count = 0;
}

void CounterType::increment()
{
    count++;
}

void CounterType::decrement()
{
    if (count > 0)
        count--;
}

int CounterType::getCount()
{
    return count;
}

void CounterType::output(ostream& outStream)
{
    outStream << count;
}
```

And here is the error.

> Error 1 error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000330) "void __cdecl decrement(void)" (?decrement@@$$FYAXXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)J:\MCM 10.05\MCM 10.05\MCM10.obj MCM 10.05

Comment: Oh man! You need some C++ instructor or a book! :)

Answer (score 5):

You are declaring global functions `increment()`, `decrement()`, and `getCount()` which you never define. You get a linking error because you invoke them in `main()` and the linker cannot find their definitions.

You probably meant to invoke the member functions of the `Counter` object, like this:

```
int main()
{
    CounterType Test;

    Test.increment();
    Test.decrement();
    Test.getCount();
}
```

If that's the case, you should remove the declarations of the global functions:

```
// THESE DECLARATIONS BEFORE main() SHOULD NOT BE THERE! JUST REMOVE THEM
// void increment();
// void decrement();
// int getCount();
// void output(ostream& outStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare a global function called `decrement()` and don't define it.

There exists `CounterType::decrement()`, but that's a different function.

The same goes for `increment()` and `getCount()`.

Answer (score 1):

You did 2 mistakes :

1) By looking your code it seems, you additionally declare following functions

```
 void increment();
 void decrement();
 int getCount();
 void output(ostream& outStream);
```

You already provided their declarations in class, So now no need to declare again.

2)
Inside main you are calling functions in this manner,

```
increment();
decrement();
getCount();
```

which probably you not wants to do, because calling in this way will invoke global functions. The correct way to call class functions is by class object

```
Test.increment();
Test.decrement();
Test.getCount();
```

Just by correcting this 2 changes, your program is ready and good to go. :)